# How can I create a three variable port AND (logic circuit)

Tags: circuitikz

experts of TikZ. I'm trying to do a simple thing: create the logic circuit S=A.B.C with three lines entering the AND port (not two!). [image: what I want]

I thank you in advance, legendary heroes!

Edit.: All I can do is this:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0, 2) node[and port](myand){}
        (myand.in 1) node[anchor=east]{A}
        (myand.in 2) node[anchor=east]{B}
        (myand.in 3) node[anchor=east]{C}
        (myand.out 4) node[anchor=west]{S};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please refer section 4.21.6 of the manual -- https://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf

Comment: I download and study circuitikz manual, and nothing of the sort is explained. Sorry for not further looking at another manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0, 2) node[and port, number inputs=3](myand){}
        (myand.in 1) node[anchor=east]{A}
        (myand.in 2) node[anchor=east]{B}
        (myand.in 3) node[anchor=east]{C}
        ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

for the out side

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0, 2) node[and port, number inputs=3](myand){}
        (myand.in 1) node[anchor=east]{A}
        (myand.in 2) node[anchor=east]{B}
        (myand.in 3) node[anchor=east]{C}
        (myand.out) node[anchor=west]{S}
        ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, +1. To have the shape the OP posted, use `\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}`.